# How to make different size text in same line

Tags: javascript, html, createjs

How can I make different text size in same text code?

```
new createjs.Text("Bigger"+"Smaller "+iMoney.toFixed(2),"bold 15px Digital-7", "#137718");
```

All text size 15px but I want that words **"Bigger"** would have **30px**

Thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
document.getElementById("demo-id").innerHTML="<span class=\"big\">Bigger</span>smaller";
```

in css:

```
.big{
    font-size: 30px;
}
#demo{
    font-size: 15px;
}
```

`demo-id` is the id of that Div element where you want to print this.

Comment: To add to this answer, if you need more complicated text in EaselJS, this is the best way. Unfortunately Canvas-based text is very limited, so your best option for something more complex is to use a DIV, and then wrap it in the EaselJS DOMElement class to align and transition it with other EaselJS content. You can not layer it within the EaselJS stage content, but it is at least an approach that gives you something better for text support.